# How to combine 2 SQL queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this my first query:

```
SELECT (Temperature) + 273.15  FROM tbl_Temperature;
```

(`Temperature` is the column name and `tbl_Temperature` is the table name.)

Data in database `dbTemp`:

```
25,3
26,7
28,4
```

(This are Temperature in Celsius)

```
output
272,45
273,85
275,55
```

(this are temperature in Kelvin)

This is my second query:

```
SELECT MAX (Temperature) FROM tbl_Temperature;
```

Data in database `dbTemp`:

```
25,3
26,7
28,4
```

Output

```
28,4
```

(This are Temperature in Celsius)

I want to combine these queries.

Data in database `dbTemp`:

```
25,3
26,7
28,4
```

(This are Temperature in Celsius)

Desired output

```
272,45
273,85
275,55

max: 275,55
```

(This are temperature in Kelvin)

So what I want is that it shows the data in `Kelvin` and the maximum in `Kelvin`.

Comment: You fixed the 273.15 in your query, but not in the results. Please consider fixing those lines, too. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to do:

```
SELECT Temperature + 273.15  FROM tbl_Temperature;
UNION ALL
SELECT  'max: ' + cast(MAX (Temperature)+ 273.15 as nvarchar)  FROM tbl_Temperature;
```

Comment: it only shows the max in kelvin, i also want the complete table

Comment: @nordincraft It seems like this answer is using a locale where `.` is the decimal separator, you probably just need to switch the `.`s to `,`s